# Vamos ser críticos: jul 2014 Autoavaliação do site

Tags: debate, site-evaluation

Todos nós amamos o [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), mas há um mundo de pessoas lá fora que precisam de respostas às próprias perguntas e nem mesmo sabem que este site existe. Quando eles chegam do Google, qual será sua primeira impressão? Vamos tentar ver este site pelos olhos de alguém que nunca o visitou antes e verificar como nos comparamos com o restante da 'Rede.

A [fila de análise de autoavaliação do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/site-eval) é aberta e preenchida com 10 perguntas que foram feitas e respondidas no último trimestre. 
Faça algumas pesquisas no Google para verificar a facilidade de encontrar as respostas e compare as que temos com as informações de outros sites.

No entanto, a classificação das perguntas é apenas uma parte do quebra-cabeças. Você vê um padrão de perguntas que devem estar encerradas mas não estão? Perguntas ou respostas que precisariam de edição? Algo que vai realmente bem? **Publique uma resposta abaixo para compartilhar suas ideias** e discuta essas perguntas e a integridade do site com seus companheiros usuários!

Comment: Isto é um post automático?

Comment: É. Mas é legal, não é?

Comment: Ficou muito bom :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, isso vai servir para quer? Destacar posts no Google após o lançamento?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Eu entendo que isso seja para a própria comunidade (incluindo o staff da Stack Exchange) avaliar como o site está indo, e detectar o que pode ser melhorado.

Comment: @bfavaretto, o resultado será divulgado aqui? Ou será apenas algo que o staff terá acesso?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Não sei. Nós moderadores já temos estatísticas básicas sobre a avaliação dessas 10 perguntas. Se não houver nenhuma proibição oficial, posso postar os números aqui quando a avaliação terminar. Vou checar com o Gabe.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Olha só, o sistema respondeu sozinho com as estatísticas, e aceitou a própria resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu fiz a pergunta pois não sabia qual seria o posicionamento do sistema/staff com relação aos dados coletados. Fico bastante contente de ver que por padrão o objetivo é divulgar o resultado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Resultados finais

- [O que "branch", "tag" e "trunk" realmente significam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20989/o-que-branch-tag-e-trunk-realmente-significam)

**Pontuação líquida: 47** (Excelente: 47, Satisfatória: 11, Precisa de melhorias: 0)

---

- [Como enviar e processar N formulários distintos com ajax sem dar refresh na pagina?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17630/como-enviar-e-processar-n-formul%c3%a1rios-distintos-com-ajax-sem-dar-refresh-na-pagi)

**Pontuação líquida: 15** (Excelente: 22, Satisfatória: 21, Precisa de melhorias: 7)

---

- [Thread Safe e sua ligação com Collections](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19353/thread-safe-e-sua-liga%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-collections)

**Pontuação líquida: 14** (Excelente: 18, Satisfatória: 34, Precisa de melhorias: 4)

---

- [Como fazer Colisão em jogo com Java 2D plataforma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20962/como-fazer-colis%c3%a3o-em-jogo-com-java-2d-plataforma)

**Pontuação líquida: 13** (Excelente: 19, Satisfatória: 25, Precisa de melhorias: 6)

---

- [Esconder código fonte do arquivo php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17770/esconder-c%c3%b3digo-fonte-do-arquivo-php)

**Pontuação líquida: 13** (Excelente: 16, Satisfatória: 38, Precisa de melhorias: 3)

---

- [Query para busca de relacionamentos no Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19139/query-para-busca-de-relacionamentos-no-oracle)

**Pontuação líquida: 4** (Excelente: 11, Satisfatória: 25, Precisa de melhorias: 7)

---

- [Calculos dinâmicos no Rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17616/calculos-din%c3%a2micos-no-rails)

**Pontuação líquida: 2** (Excelente: 7, Satisfatória: 27, Precisa de melhorias: 5)

---

- [carregar processo independente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22275/carregar-processo-independente)

**Pontuação líquida: 0** (Excelente: 11, Satisfatória: 26, Precisa de melhorias: 11)

---

- [Usando o Symfony como iniciar o banco de dados automaticamente ao implantar o projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22166/usando-o-symfony-como-iniciar-o-banco-de-dados-automaticamente-ao-implantar-o-pr)

**Pontuação líquida: -10** (Excelente: 5, Satisfatória: 24, Precisa de melhorias: 15)

---

- [ArrayList em JAVA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19135/arraylist-em-java)

**Pontuação líquida: -28** (Excelente: 3, Satisfatória: 16, Precisa de melhorias: 31)

---

Answer (score 20):

Não tenho nada de muito original a dizer. O site está de parabéns, possui excelentes profissionais de TI respondendo todo tipo de questão em diversos nichos. Também temos uma galera empolgada que levanta respostas para perguntas extremamente especializadas / sofisticadas (tenho que admitir; atualmente para perguntas mais sofisticadas consigo mais respostas aqui do que no SOen).

Em termos de perguntas que considero ruins (ainda que não necessariamente fosse o caso de fechá-las e sim de melhorá-las), percebi que algumas perguntas demonstram uma falta de entendimento conceitual sobre determinado assunto, e para piorar não incluem exemplos que demonstrem o problema na prática.

Enquanto tenho que dizer que sou culpado por produzir questões do tipo "muralha de texto" (no extremo oposto); sou fã de questões que seguem o seguinte template:

> Estou tentando fazer **isso** conforme as práticas demonstradas nos
>   links *x*,*y* e *z*. Porém, estou com a seguinte dúvida para
>   **codificar / estrutura / modelar / *ar** tal coisa. Segue um exemplo do que fiz:
>
> ```
>   1 a N Pedaços de código pequenos (só não vale em Whitespace), 
>   xmls exóticos
>   estrutura de pastas
>   imagens da UI
>   Diagramas ou "ASCII Art" de programador
>   links para o JSFiddle, etc.
> ```
>
> Esbarrei **nesse problema** / **nesse aspecto que seria interessante melhorar** / **nesse  comportamento que não sei se é correto** abaixo demonstrado e gostaria de saber
>   como proceder?
>
> ```
> Stack trace, 
> imagem mostrando um problema de UI, etc.
> ```

Esse tipo de questão é certamente mais densa, porém nos dá maiores subsídios para responder (e de quebra, motores de busca encontram mais termos para indexar). Se o autor teve algum problema de entendimento conceitual ao menos o que ele quer ficou bem demonstrado. Se ele teve um problema técnico este também ficou bem demonstrado. Finalmente, se ele está tentando usar a técnica errada para determinado problema isso também ficou demonstrado.

Do outro lado estão as questões do tipo:

> Como escrevo uma API para fazer café? Dá para ligar a torradeira junto? E se eu quiser passar mel na torrada? Existe um combo de cafeteira e torradeira com entrada USB? Dá para ligar a cafeteira no Wi-Fi? Dá pra fazer um aplicativo Android para comandar a cafeteira ou tem que ser Web?

Esse tipo de questão (foco no "como", e com requisitos embaralhados, sem nenhum subsídio técnico ou conceitual) geralmente são repletas de problemas e demonstram pouca ou nenhuma pesquisa sobre o assunto. Algumas já estão sendo corretamente notificadas (situação em que boa parte das vezes o OP desiste ou encontra a solução assim que começa a fazer sua pesquisa); outras, porém, persistem e encontram respostas (parte das vezes descontextualizadas).

O problema disso (que talvez não seja um problema)? Esse conteúdo também será indexado pelo Google.

Os *guidelines* já estão aí para lidar com esse tipo de coisa. Acho que o principal ponto aqui é que sejamos firmes nesse aspecto. Veja que firme não significa áspero, precisamos apenas fazer cumprir a nossa política (que já existe) e notificar autores de perguntas problemáticas. Outro ponto importante é desestimular quem se apressa em responder essas perguntas (evitando que o OP tome o caminho fácil de aceitar a primeira resposta que vier para não ter trabalho). Comentários são nossos amigos, principalmente na hora de educar alguém que teve a boa vontade de responder (e muitas vezes não sabe que está contribuindo com um possível problema).

Comment: Gostei da definição "muralha de texto".

Comment: Li isso em algum canto; se não foi no metão ou no meta do SOen foi em algum blog comentando sobre o SOen hehehe.

Comment: É, no metão costumam dizer *wall of text*.

Comment: "atualmente para perguntas mais sofisticadas consigo mais respostas aqui do que no SOen" Eu me sinto da mesma maneira. Com frequência, o tipo de dúvida que eu mais tenho não se encaixa bem nos moldes do SO (ou mesmo no programmers). Mas aqui, o pessoal tem demonstrado não só interesse como bom-senso ao tratar das "áreas cinza". Pra mim pelo menos isso tem sido muito útil, me permitindo "desagarrar" em questões não tão pontuais, mas que ainda me trazem muita dor-de-cabeça na prática.

Comment: Vi essa pergunta e lembrei na hora da sua torradeira: [Como conectar câmera DVR em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42880/3117)

Answer (score 11):

## Quando eles chegam do Google, qual será sua primeira impressão?

Bom, posso descrever a minha experiência, que foi no SO Gringo: **Nossa, que legal! Achei exatamente a resposta que eu precisava para o meu problema!** Acho que aqui está se encaminhando rapidamente pra isso. Aliás, alguns vícios do SO Gringo foram já combatidos aqui, como por exemplo "leia o link tal: (link)".

Falta só esclarecer aos novos visitantes que aqui não é um fórum e estimular ainda mais o tour, que é bem didático.

## Você vê um padrão de perguntas que devem estar encerradas mas não estão?

Sim, as "filosóficas", aquelas que se aproximam de uma discussão (embora tenha gente que não concorde e que ache a discussão "estimulante"), por exemplo:

> É bom/ruim usar (recurso genérico que existe em várias linguagens)? Quais as vantagens? Quais os defeitos?
>
> Por que linguagem tal é melhor que linguagem tal?

Ou então aquelas perguntas tendenciosas, que começam meio que afirmando uma prática ou conceito que o autor da pergunta gosta e/ou concorda:

> Por que devo usar o conceito tal?

Vejam que não acho ruim a discussão. Apenas acho que ela foge ao propósito do site, que tem algumas ferramentas pra evitar a discussão, como nos comentários, por exemplo, ou o próprio meta.

## O que ainda pode ser melhorado?

Os Wikis são ainda bastante subutilizados, embora bem preenchidos. Precisamos encontrar maneiras das pessoas lerem este material. Minha sugestão seria os autores de respostas citarem as tags dentro de suas respostas.

Comment: +1 Por lembrar dos wikis. Sobre as perguntas filosóficas, não está bem claro pra mim de quais você não gosta (se qualquer pergunta conceitual, ou das que pedem opinião – estas últimas, já combatidas no site).

Comment: @bfavaretto São aquelas em que o objetivo não é uma resposta que necessariamente esclareça um problema ou uma dúvida, mas que crie um debate, às vezes parcial. São de dois tipos: as tendenciosas e aquelas que não chegam a lugar algum.

Comment: Em geral eu concordo sobre as perguntas filosóficas, inclusive tenho visto esse tipo de pergunta crescendo um pouco em frequência nos últimos tempos. Só é preciso ter cuidado pra diferenciar entre o que é conceitual, mas objetivo, e o que só abre espaço pra debate. Seu primeiro exemplo, na minha opinião, é um tópico perfeitamente válido: afinal, se diferentes linguagens empregam o mesmo conceito (ex.: lambdas, closures...) compreender a lógica por trás do mesmo não só te permite usá-lo bem na sua plataforma de escolha quanto facilita o aprendizado ao entrar em contato com uma diferente.

Comment: P.S. Perguntas "que não chegam a lugar algum" são difíceis de se determinar a priori, pois já vi muita pergunta ruim receber respostas excelentes. Mas concordo 100% sobre as tendenciosas, tem pergunta que parece estar tentando "vender" um conceito ou prática, mais do que esclarecer dúvidas sobre ele. Eu chamaria esse tipo de pergunta de "evangelizadora"... :P

Comment: Sobre as perguntas "filosóficas": não seria interessante então estimular que as respostas para essas perguntas (e até mesmo a pergunta) partam para o lado explicativo? Exemplificando: trocar perguntas do tipo "Por que X é melhor que Y?" por "Quais as diferenças entre X e Y?", e quem responde poderia postar as vantagens e desvantagens de X e Y em contextos/ambientes diferentes e ajudar o autor a achar a melhor opção no contexto que ele quer inserir X e Y. O ideal seria fugir de discussões-sem-fim e focar em respostas mais técnicas.