# Estamos vivenciando uma experiência meritocrática?

Tags: debate

### PREÂMBULOS

A estratégia de "empoderar o mérito", supostamente, para a comunidade aqui do SOpt, pode significar:

> Meritocracia (...) é um sistema de gestão que considera o mérito, como aptidão, a razão principal para se atingir posição de topo. As posições hierárquicas são conquistadas, em tese, com base no merecimento (...). Constitui-se uma forma ou método de seleção e, num sentido mais amplo, pode ser considerada uma ideologia governativa. [pt.wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meritocracia)
>
> A meritocracia no mundo do software livre é uma meritocracia entre membros que têm condições iguais. Todo mundo ali é programador, tem formação, acesso a computador, internet, etc. Dadas todas essas condições, aí realmente fica aquela coisa do “quem contribui mais, apita mais”, [hisham](http://hisham.hm/2014/03/20/sobre-meritocracia-e-igualdade-na-sociedade-e-no-software-livre/).
>
> Direta ou indiretamente, todos os dias falamos de meritocracia, alguns exemplos claros são: entrevista de emprego, vestibular (...). [rafaelalmeida](http://rafaelalmeida.net/blog/2014/02/01/o-que-a-meritocracia-diz-sobre-voce/)

### PERGUNTA

**Acreditam que o SO, em particular o SOpt é uma "meritocracia"?** Caberia uma auto-avaliação nesse sentido? Caberiam sugestões para melhorar a "matemática do mérito" utilizada no SOpt?

---

EDIT (Re. comentarios @bfavaretto e @brasofilo)

### Considerações pragmáticas e um pouco de opinião

Acho que a discussão pode tomar diversos rumos interessantes… Eu havia colocado a palavra “matemática” no título pois acho que é o que menos se discute, o “modelo matemático do mérito”, apesar de o SO depender essencialmente desse modelo.

Também sugiro, para evitar muita dispersão, um pouco de pragmatismo.
Os usuários do SO possuem mérito em função do que *“o SO considera mérito”*… E, pragmaticamente, não é a opinião do Joel que determina isso:

- O Stackoverlow (SO) sobrevive e faz sucesso em função do número de visitas que recebe. Esse é o “alimento” do Stackoverlow. As páginas do SO não precisam ser inteligentes, importantes, ou sábias, *elas precisam gerar visitação e [page-views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_view)(!)*.
- O usuário do SO precisa ganhar mais mérito quando gerar, direta ou indiretamente, mais *page-views*.
- O conceito pessoal de "qualidade de conteúdo" do Joel, ou mesmo da comunidade, não afeta o SO: se o conteúdo gerado pelo usuário é simples ou aprofundado, se é plágio ou cópia com citação, se é texto educado ou ríspido, etc. Tudo isso, supostamente, se *auto-regulamenta pela comunidade e pela própria Internet*.
- … Em seguida o "mérito" tem haver com os objetivos da própria comunidade. Cada um de nós participa, visita, etc. porque tem uma visão e percepção do site, e um  objetivo, similar aos demais visitantes e colaboradores. Como colocou o @Cigano, entrou no Stackoverflow porque pensou "[Nossa, que legal! Achei exatamente a resposta que eu precisava para o meu problema!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1767/4186)".

É assim que funciona, é um sucesso e roda redondo porque um alimenta o outro, o site e o usuário gerando *page-views*… E em time que está ganhando não se mexe! Então tudo o que podemos fazer (de pragmaticamente útil) é:

1. Esclarecer melhor a comunidade, **sermos mais transparentes e precisos** com nós mesmos, **sobre as finalidades do SOpt e o *conceito de mérito* aqui praticado**. 
   PS: e concordarei com o @Gabe, quando ele nos lembrar que justamente o SO-Meta ajuda a construir esse esclarecimento. A intensão aqui é apenas consolidar um pouco, em uma só página, o assunto "mérito" e a visão da comunidade SOpt sobre ele.
2. Discutir e **sugerir pequenas melhoras, pequenos ajustes** -- eu acredito em particular no ajuste da “matemática do mérito”, para reduzir as enormes desigualdades de riqueza, usar em algum lugar a função [log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), e usar [outras fontes como a quantidade de votos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1813/4186). Sugerir não faz mal a ninguém, e de quabra a discussão vai alimentar mais *page-views*.

Enfim, acredito que possamos até ter dois tipos de resposta, e vota-las separadamente a cada um desses tópicos.

---

NOTA: talvez tenhamos que discernir entre dois lados relevantes da *metritocracia*: A) a *formação e manutenção da comunidade* (incluso o potencial para oferecer recompensas), que foi meu enfoque na pergunta;  B) a relação *"mérito vs democracia"* (politica) nas eleições, que acredito ser melhor discutido em página separada.

Comment: Só pra deixar explícito, a "matemática do mérito" que vc se refere é a contagem de pontos através dos votos? E também, qual seu conceito de "real meritocracia"?

Comment: Aonde você quer chegar com esse questionamento? Parece haver algo mais por detrás da pergunta. Um sentimento de injustiça, talvez?

Comment: Prezados, fiz uma edição, digam lá se melhorou. Fiquem a vontade para também editar.

Comment: A proposta aqui é apenas discutir... *Aviso* portanto, de ante-mão, que *não haverá "resposta aceita" para a presente pergunta*. PS: não faria sentido eu sozinho destacar uma das respostas, em detrimento do destaque das colocações mais votadas.

Comment: Parabéns Peter Krauss, um bom questionamento.

Comment: Todos deveriam começar com 10k de reputação e quando um upvote for dado, sua reputação ser transferida para o cara que recebeu upvote. Quando for downvote, a reputação do cara ser transferida para quem deu o downvote. Conforme mais usuários se registram, mais reputação circula.

Comment: @Patrick Talvez você devesse postar isso como pedido de novo-recurso, ou na outra pergunta do Peter. Mas não acho essa idéia sustentável, ela incentiva o downvote e desincentiva o upvote!

Comment: Isso é um sistema baseado na consciência de cada um.

Answer (score 13):

> Nota: essa resposta foi dada antes da edição do OP. Muito do que foi dito aqui reflete considerações já muito bem feitas na pergunta (a duplicidade de "méritos" - mérito em promover o site, e mérito no objeto do site).

O sistema de moderação do SOpt (e demais) é basicamente isto: quem contribui mais, ganha mais reputação, e quem tem mais reputação tem maior poder de moderação. Pelo menos essa é a teoria. Na prática, costuma funcionar bem, mas há aqui alguns links quebrados.

Essa é minha interpretação do sistema por trás do site:

#### Os pontos de reputação são baseados em mérito

**Falso** - os pontos de reputação são consequência direta das ações dos outros usuários. Todo usuário [exceto os recém-chegados] tem o mesmo número de votos, e seu voto tem o mesmo peso. Isso significa que quem atribui o voto não está necessariamente qualificado para avaliar o mérito alheio. Por essa razão alguma orientação "de cima" é necessária - já deve ter ouvido a frase "a popularidade de uma postagem não é necessariamente indício de qualidade"...

Pelo menos esse é o caso geral. Mas no caso específico de um site cujo assunto são as ciências exatas, acaba que a coisa vai por esse caminho mesmo. Numa ciência mais *soft* (ou numa *hard* mesmo, só que incrivelmente complexa, como a Medicina) é um pouquinho mais difícil de se avaliar quem está certo e quem está errado - isso quando o certo e o errado existem... Não estou dizendo que essas comunidades não funcionam - funcionam sim, como pode-se ver nos diversos sites da SE. O que quero dizer é que nesse caso é mais difícil se falar em mérito, pois recai naquele velho problema: **como julgar alguém que tem mais conhecimento que você?**

Esse é um problema prevalente na **vida**. Talvez quem tenha conhecimento de ciências sociais possa ter boas ideias para ajudar a identificar o mérito, ou mesmo promovê-lo, como você propõe. Mas eu pessoalmente não faço *a menor ideia*: eu só conto com meu próprio conhecimento para avaliar os outros, e meu conhecimento é limitadíssimo - sou experiente em um domínio bastante estreito, e ignorante na grande maioria dos outros domínios. Já cometi, cometo, e provavelmente continuarei cometendo diversos erros de julgamento por causa disso.

Mas aqui, por outro lado, é fácil: informações incorretas são rapidamente identificadas seja por meio de lógica ou de experimentação. E quando uma postagem incorreta é bem avaliada, a "indignação" de alguns acaba por mover a comunidade toda no sentido de corrigir o erro. Quem se lembra do caso da pergunta sobre validação de CPFs sabe do que eu estou falando... :P

#### Quem contribui mais ganha mais reputação

**Verdadeiro** - o SOpt é um sistema **gamificado**, o que significa que seu sistema de pontuação e premiação (reputação, medalhas, ranking...) é todo voltado a **estimular um comportamento específico**. A reputação não avalia só qualidade: ela avalia qualidade x quantidade. Mas principalmente quantidade.

O melhor exemplo disso é o [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet): 700 mil de reputação no SOen. Agora, adivinha qual é a sua média de upvotes? 700,994 rep / 29,806 respostas = 23.5! Uma "postagem típica" do Jon Skeet gera apenas 2 upvotes (*Edit:* como apontado por @Math, não é bem assim - pois muitos votos positivos não geram reputação dado o cap). Se considerar que algumas (muitas) de suas respostas têm mais de 100 upvotes (quase 5 páginas) daí se conclui que ele possui uma enorme quantidade de posts com 0 upvotes (mais de 30 páginas).

Ou seja, pra se chegar ao topo, só dedicando *bastante* tempo ao site. Se dividirmos os mesmos 700 mil pelo seu tempo de participação (5 anos e 10 meses) temos 700,994 / (5 * 12 + 10) / 30 = 333.8! Isso é um Mortarboard e meio por dia!!! Isso mostra, sobretudo, que não é só por causa dos seus posts mais "famosos" que ele atingiu essa marca - somente isso não seria suficiente, dado o limite de 200 por dia via upvotes. Boa parte desses pontos vêm de respostas aceitas - o que mostra que a contribuição diária dele é bastante frequente.

Existem sistemas melhores para avaliar o mérito (ou a habilidade). O sistema ELO do xadrez, por exemplo. Mas o objetivo dos pontos de reputação não é classificar ninguém: é estimular os usuários a continuarem participando, continuarem respondendo/perguntando, pois somente através de participação contínua é que se mantém o fluxo de reputação. Especialista parado não serve pra muita coisa... (as contribuições passadas têm valor, sim, mas a ideia do site é que quem vier aqui perguntar coisas novas consiga boas respostas)

#### Quem tem mais reputação tem maior poder de moderação

**Verdadeiro** - seja por meio dos votos para fechar (inacessíveis para usuários novos), votos para remover postagens, permissão para ver postagens excluídas... A influência de um usuário "veterano" é certamente maior que a de um novato. Mas veja bem que isso se assemelha mais a uma senioridade do que a uma meritocracia (pois como já dito, a reputação é mais influenciada pela quantidade de postagens do que pela qualidade individual de cada uma delas).

#### Quem tem maior poder de moderação tem mais influência (i.e. "apita mais")

**Falso** - É só ver os diversos casos em que um usuário acusa outro de "usar mal seu privilégio de moderação". O fato é que os *early adopters* - aqueles que estiveram presentes no site desde sua concepção - acabaram por "moldar" boa parte do site de acordo com a sua visão. Não quer dizer que eles tenham monopólio sobre as regras do site, mas a influência inicial deles continua "viva".

Como? Simples: cada usuário novo que entra no site encontra determinadas regras. Sem poder (a princípio) para mudá-las, ele se adapta (ou vai embora). À medida que ele ganha maior poder de moderação, ele começa a aplicá-lo em conformidade com aquelas regras. O que só as reforça. A coisa vai virando uma bola de neve, e embora mudanças sempre sejam possíveis, a "cultura" do site já está mais ou menos bem definida.

(É por essa razão, inclusive, que as primeiras semanas do beta privado são tão importantes - pois se quisermos que o site saia "certo", é preciso acertar desde o início.)

#### Parece então que *não é* uma meritocracia, não?

Não mesmo, se entendi bem o sentido da meritocracia. Veja bem que é até possível quem quem "chegue ao topo" [do sistema de pontuação] o faça pelos seus méritos, mas isso não o coloca "no topo" - do sistema de gestão/moderação. Na verdade nem há esse topo: uma vez que o usuário atinge ["Usuário Confiável"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), ele está de igual pra igual com todo outro usuário não moderador do site. Aqui somos apenas 15, mas no SOen já são mais de 2 mil (e vamos chegar lá eventualmente)

De todo modo, reitero o que disse anteriormente: o objetivo primário do sistema de pontuação do SOpt não é premiar o mérito, e sim premiar comportamentos desejáveis, que façam o site dar certo. O mérito é apenas um objetivo secundário (ex.: subsidiar o [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)), de modo que 'sugestões para melhorar a "matemática do mérito"' podem até ser bem-vindas, mas no meu entendimento dificilmente resultarão em alguma mudança - a menos que ela venha acompanhada numa melhoria também na "matemática do comportamento"... :)

---

**Adendo** - sobre o sistema de gratificações

Como sugerido pelo OP, vou dar minha opinião sobre o sistema de gratificações: de fato, ao se acumular pontos de reputação aqui se permite efetivamente dar destaque a uma pergunta por muito, muito tempo. Quem estiver disposto a torrar 2750 pontos (50+100+...+500) pode em princípio manter uma pergunta na lista "em destaque" por até 10 semanas (um pouco menos se a pergunta tiver uma resposta dele próprio).

E por que alguém faria isso? Para obter uma boa resposta, por exemplo. Na minha experiência pessoal isso não ajuda muito - pois nos assuntos em que sou experiente (programação em geral) eu raramente tenho uma pergunta que eu tenho urgência de ser respondida. Nos outros em que sou inexperiente (aqueles que demandam mais subjetividade), raramente as perguntas seriam aceitas aqui. Isso limita um tanto a utilidade do sistema de gratificações, pelo menos pra mim (e principalmente no SOen - como o escopo do SOpt é um tanto mais amplo, as possibilidades de troca de experiência aqui são maiores).

Por outro lado, devo admitir que o fato de ser um usuário bem pontuado me foi muito útil às vezes. Quando fui em frente e perguntei, mesmo achando ser uma pergunta "ruim" ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2259/215), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6776/215), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25498/215), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23185/215)) em geral tive a pergunta bem recebida (e boas respostas, que me ajudaram mais do que vocês imaginam). Tenho a impressão de que muitas delas seriam vistas de forma mais crítica se tivessem sido feitas por usuários novatos. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: P.S. Escrevi essa resposta antes de ver sua edição. Agora estou sem tempo, sequer pra ver se fui no rumo certo ou se errei a marca por um quilômetro... Mais tarde eu volto aqui pra ver melhor que rumo as coisas tomaram. :)

Comment: `Uma "postagem típica" do Jon Skeet gera apenas 2 upvotes`, na verdade o Jon Skeet recebe em média 100 upvotes diários, o que geraria uma reputação de 1K caso não houvesse o limite de 200, logo a sua conta não é válida. Jon Skeet tem mais medalhas "Nice Answer" que qualquer outra pessoa tem de medalhas.

Comment: Entretanto o pensamento foi concluído corretamente: `dado o limite de 200 por dia via upvotes. Boa parte desses pontos vêm de respostas aceitas - o que mostra que a contribuição diária dele é bastante frequente.`. Enfim, boa resposta a sua.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, aguardamos seu retorno, mas o que postou já convenceu (!), como vê pelos nossos votos... Quanto ao uso da reputação como estimulo à comunidade, acho que só faltou lembrar do **"mercado da reputação"**: o fato de você poder transferir pontos para outros (*sistema de gratificação*), faz da reputação efetivamente uma moeda, como [bitcoins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoins). Portanto existe efetivamente "riqueza", e uma espécie de poder econômico associado a ela. No SO-en  a "compra de consultoria" ajuda comprovadamente a economizar dinheiro de verdade.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, acho que um exemplo interessante para colocar em "Quem tem maior poder de moderação tem mais influência" é perguntas sobre `SEO` que foram definidas a princípio como off-topic e um usuário novo propôs que as mesmas fossem aceitas e a nota no meta está subindo (saiu de -3 para +2).

Comment: @PeterKrauss Concordo com essa questão da gratificação, de fato em algumas situações ser bem pontuado aqui ajuda a obter boas respostas (quando as mesmas não vêm por "vias normais"). Quanto ao resto, creio que muito do que falei aqui é redundante com o que você já havia percebido muito bem: que o "mérito" principal é aquele que traz page-views e mantém o site circulando. Inclusive acho que você expressou isso na pergunta bem melhor do que eu... :P

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Sinceramente, não sei o que pensar a respeito... O requisito para se votar no meta é bem baixo, de modo que se formos nos guiar somente por isso, o escopo do site poderia a princípio mudar de uma hora pra outra ao chegar uma nova "leva" de usuários. O caso do SEO foi meio atípico, pois pelo menos 8 perguntas do tipo já haviam "passado despercebidas" - aceitas e bem votadas. De modo que quando você e eu notamos que ela deveria ser off-topic pelos padrões vigentes, já havia um precedente significativo - que creio ter influenciado a decisão dos outros (a minha, pelo menos, sim).

Comment: Verdade, muitas vezes dou mais crédito por ser uma pergunta de alguém com mais reputação, até porque normalmente tem uma pergunta mais bem formulada, como é o caso dos exemplos que deste.

Answer (score 8):

## Sistema de Governo

Em minha visão particular, o SO em geral é uma mistura de "sistemas de governo".

Ele é **meritocrático** no sentido de que você recebe certos privilégios (que na verdade aumentam sua responsabilidade) e recompensas (medalhas, que não servem para nada a não ser para se exibir) quando atinge certos objetivos.

Ele também é **democrático** porque o sistema não lhe recompensa automaticamente, mas depende da ação direta dos usuários do site (voto), que podem ou não votar em alguém, independente do esforço que se faça.

Poderia até dizer que ele é um tanto **capitalista**, porque incentiva a livre iniciativa, a competição, onde o "melhor" vence, e tem uma política de gerar a menor interferência possível do "governo". A diferença é que aqui ninguém precisa declarar falência por dívida de votos... ;)

## Relações sociais

Independente da forma de governo, algo que faz parte tanto da meritocracia, quanto da democracia, quanto das relações humanas em geral, é que os "poderes" ou "méritos" dos usuários são relativos conforme a personalidade e a "aparência" de cada um.

Explico: não importa a quantidade de pontos que um usuário tenha. Se os usuários perceberem nele alguém que age em prol da comunidade, certamente ele será mais ouvido do que outro usuário que tem dezenas de milhares de pontos, mas discute a todo momento e causa mal-estar na comunidade.

Há muitos usuários por aqui que são muito respeitados, sem estar no topo do ranking, sem um diamante de moderador e sem passar o dia no site. Eles simplesmente demonstram saber como o SO funciona, serem bons programadores, ter personalidade madura e também jogam segundo as "regras", mesmo que às vezes testem um pouco os limites do SO.

## Pragmatismo?

Na parte da edição em que você fala sobre pragmatismo e *page views*, concordo com a maior parte.

Porém, há um equívoco nesse raciocínio. O SO é, até certo ponto, pragmático. A comunidade tem voz e poder, mas não podemos colocar a carroça na frente dos bois.

O modelo do SO foi idealizado para gerar primariamente conteúdo de qualidade e relevante. A quantidade de visualizações do site é uma consequência disso, mas até onde eu li e ouvi do Joel e do Jeff, isso não será colocado em primazia, nunca.

Isso implica em que, o fato de um certo tipo de conteúdo gerar mais visualizações não é garantia de que ele é de interesse para o site.

Por exemplo, esses dias assisti a uma [apresentação do próprio Jeff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEc6Eyogb9Y) (co-fundador do SO) sobre o sistema do SO. Em um determinado momento, ele falou sobre a questão de aceitarem no SO perguntas sobre o mercado de trabalho. Então disse que esse tipo de pergunta geralmente atrai bastante visitas e muito interesse, porém a informação é rapidamente defasada, geralmente é localizada e o conteúdo torna-se rapidamente inútil.

Esse é o motivo para o site ter fama de ser mais "fechado" ou "linha dura".

Então, creio que, embora a sugestão de ganhar mais mérito por *pageview* seja até interessante, os idealizadores do site iriam argumentar que isso atrairia conteúdo de baixa qualidade e a razão de ser do SO deixaria de existir.

O SO seria então mais um fórum como tantos outros. Pior, os usuárias começariam a focar no SEO ao fazer perguntas e respostas.

Veja, não estou dizendo que a equipe do SO não vai ou não deve melhorar o site, nem que não iriam aceitar sua sugestão, nem que o site seria realmente ruim se mudasse, nem que eles não ligam para a quantidade de visualizações, nem que eles são tão idealistas que nunca mudariam a forma como o SO funciona.

## "Enormes desigualdades de riqueza?"

Confesso que não entendi a parte onde você menciona desigualdade. Isso seria algum tipo de sistema socialista com redistribuição de renda?

Quanto à aplicação de um logaritmo, seria para desacelerar a pontuação dos usuários? Por exemplo, se eu tenho mais de 10k votos, então cada voto passaria a valor `8` ao invés de `10` pontos?

Eu confesso que é intimidante, por exemplo, entrar no SOen e ver usuários com centenas de milhares de pontos. Porém, normalizar os pontos numa escala logarítmica (posso estar errado) apenas iria dar uma sensação de proximidade, sendo que o esforço para subir no *ranking* seria apenas uma ilusão.

## Considerações

Confesso que não sou a melhor pessoa para falar sobre essas questões de política, relações sociais ou mesmo sobre o SO. Há muitas pessoas aqui com muito mais tempo de SO do que eu, além de mais experiência de vida. Porém, espero ter esclarecido alguns pontos.

Enfim, meu resumo particular sobre o SO é que ele é um sistema que prioriza a qualidade, mas deixando a decisão sobre o que é qualidade para os próprios usuários e beneficia aqueles que melhor se adequam a esse padrão de qualidade.

Comment: Você pode não se achar a melhor pessoa para falar dessas coisas, mas o que você discute, principalmente na parte das relações sociais e na do pragmatismo, complementa muito bem a resposta do mgibsonbr. E tenho que confessar que apesar de tudo o que foi debatido, ainda não entendi direito de onde vem a pergunta, nem para onde vai o debate.

Comment: Creio que as "desigualdades de riqueza" e "função log" se referem a expressar a reputação numa base logarítmica. É mais ou menos como num RPG, onde a cada "nível" que se alcança fica mais e mais difícil "subir de nível". Na minha opinião, isso seria extremamente contraproducente: se um usuário experiente começa a sentir que seu esforço não está "dando resultado", isso o **desestimula** a participar mais - e não o contrário, que é o objetivo do sistema de gamificação. Além disso, o resultado final ficaria mais parecido com um "sistema de castas" hehe.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, e demais. Acho que com o [modelo de referência](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1830/4186) (precisaria ser consensual, editem a vontade!) podemos fazer colocações mais claras e objetivas. Quanto a usar um "função-riqueza", acho que de forma alguma desestimula, pelo contrário, **precisamos estimular os milhares de usuários "pobres"**. Exemplo: se os *pontos mínimos* para se usar de *gratificação* fossem crescendo com a riqueza, o mais pobre poderia gratificar com 5 pontos, e o milionário começaria com um mínimo 500 ou mesmo 1000. A proposta é discutir que função seria essa.

Comment: @PeterKrauss No SOen há 370 perguntas em destaque. Quem consegue ler todas elas? Se todo mundo pudesse gratificar com o que tem: 1) essa lista cresceria absurdamente; 2) menos pessoas as consultaria, pois a chance de encontrar uma pergunta interessante seria menor, e a recompensa média também seria menor. Da mesma forma, se aumentássemos o requisito para gratificar dos usuários com mais pontos, isso reduziria sua "riqueza" mas aumentaria seu "poder": as perguntas que eles escolhessem como importantes atrairiam os olhares de todos (pois valem mais se respondidas). Queremos isso?

Comment: Acho que [captou a proposta, estamos discutindo as possibilidades](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1836/4186) (!). Vamos lá. Da sua colocação interpreto o seguinte: a função "aquecedora do mercado" não deveria interferir demais, usuários novatos oferecendo gratificações de 5 pontinhos seria demais... Ok, então melhoremos isso, imaginemos 20 pontos de mínimo para os novatos e 300 pontos de mínimo para os milionários.

Answer (score 1):

... Agradeço a todos, leitores e redatores, por terem se aventurado nesse mar desconhecido, com mais cara de Sociologia do que Computação.
Também estou aqui de aventureiro.

Somos todos programadores, de modo que todos "falamos a mesma língua" quando discutimos algoritmos e modelos matemáticos.
Somos todos cidadãos de países imperfeitos, como o Brasil.  "Vivenciar uma experiência meritocrática", como colocado no título, é algo estimulante, que nos faz pensar em usar experiencias do mundo virtual para sugerir aperfeiçoamentos no o mundo real...
Isso responde, em parte, a quem comenta "não entendi direito de onde vem a pergunta, nem para onde vai o debate".

O debate começou a se fixar num rumo, depois das respostas do @mgibsonbr e do @utluiz.

Esse post não é bem uma resposta, foi aberto como **Wiki**, para quem quiser ajudar: é uma tentativa de estabelecer modelo descritivo de consenso, para em cima dela poder debater conceitos e sugestões.

## MODELO DE REFERÊNCIA

Apresenta-se abaixo o que se observa do SO (StackOverflow). É como uma tentativa de "tirar uma foto do SO", e depois descreve-la aqui em palavras e gráficos. É longe de ser uma verdade, mas pode ser baseado em consensos e boas aproximações (!), e pode ser um ponto de partida para discussões. Permite conceituar, entre outros:

- *Cilo de vida do voto*: expressa o comportamento típico da quantidade de votos de um *post* no tempo.
- *Dinâmica do usuário*: modelo de *maturidade* do usuário.
- *Causas mais comuns para a popularidade*: considerações e "estatísticas" que apontam para as fontes das "grandes riquezas".

Convencionemos denominar *"gráfico VxT"* ao gráfico de votos *vs* tempo.

### Dinâmica do voto

A primeira coisa que chama atenção no voto, e na forma como recebemos "pontos reputação" (doravante apenas *pontos*), é o seu comportamento no tempo.

Quem veio do Stackoverflow inglês (SO-en), e teve a oportunidade de postar  algo (pergunta ou resposta) popular, sabe que existem dois momentos importantes:

- *origem*: quando você faz o *post* no SO, no mesmo dia ou semana já tem um *feedback* se o assunto for inédito e  minimamente popular. Há uma certa concentração de votos nesse inicio, que se evidenciaria por um pico no inicio do *gráfico VxT*.
- *vida útil*: enquanto o assunto estiver em pauta na comunidade, ele vai render um certo pinga-pinga contínuo de votos, que vai diminuindo (devido o número de votantes finito) mas não tem data para acabar.
- *morte*: não existe "atestado de óbito", mas se o assunto "perde a graça" ou a tecnologia tratada nele sucateia, teremos um número de visitas estagnado indicando isso.

Podemos chamar isso de **"ciclo de vida do voto"**: um *gráfico VxT* de pico no inicio e barriguinha deitada, longa, se esvaindo com os meses. 
PS: alguém teria uma imagem para ilustrar?

#### Correlações

Num *caso típico* ocorrem correlações:

- Entre pergunta e resposta: só depois da pergunta existem respostas, e em geral perguntas com mais votos (populares no SO) possuem também respostas com mais votos.
- Entre gratificações e votos: o anúncio  da gratificação "chama votos".
- Entre *page-views* e votos: a visitação (popularidade na Internet) também "chama votos".

### Dinâmica e perfil do usuário

A maior parte das respostas que damos no SO, tem "morte rápida", não tem no *gráfico VxT* a tal da barriguinha deitada do pinga-pinga.
O pinga-pinga de votos é exclusividade da popularidade e dos assuntos longevos. É com grande satisfação, portanto, que o usuário percebe os seus primeiros rendimentos de longo prazo  — como numa caderneta de poupança, só depois da espera e de um certo investimento, é que surge o pinga-pinga de antigos *posts*.

Assim podemos fazer uma primeira classificação dos usuários quanto à sua relação com os votos:

- **Usuários novos**: não apenas recém-chegados, mas também aqueles "com cara" de recém-chegado, que ainda não se entusiasmaram pelo SO.
- **Usuários maduros**: aqueles que, mesmo não sendo grandes frequentadores, já sentiram e recebem o pinga-pinga de antigos *posts*. Passam a ter um novo estímulo, tanto  para ficar no SO, como para se preocupar com a qualidade do que postam.

Em seguida, a distinção mais importante entre usuários é quanto ao uso do recurso da gratificação:

- **praticam gratificação**:  são participantes de um verdadeiro [*mercado*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercado), no sentido econômico do termo. O usuário precisa ter uns pontinhos sobrando, então se torna um "[agente econômico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agente_econ%C3%B4mico)" mais eficaz na comunidade... Em geral apenas *usuários maduros* participam desse "mercado". 
  PS: outro efeito disso é que  mais perguntas, de alta especificidade e/ou alta complexidade surgem no SO. Perguntas de assuntos de maior interesse podem ser ressuscitadas, e o *ciclo de vida do voto* se repete nelas.
- **não praticam**: não possuem pontos suficientes para "sair gastando", ou preferem "ficar de fora" desse mercado, ou possuem algum outro estímulo para "acumular riqueza" e não gastar nadinha.

### Riqueza no SO

Existe uma imensa desigualdade no SO-en: 100, 1000, 2000 pontos/usuário, com mais de 90% dos usuários; contra 10k, 100k, com os detentores de enorme reputação.

Qual o significado disso? Chamemos esses pontos de "reputação" ou "mérito", qual o significado de comparar 100k com 100? Existem super-seres?  super-gênios?  O que fizeram eles para merecer tanto, enquanto os outros, a grande maioria, praticamente nada?

A resposta é que existe: *participar* intensamente, não participar, e participar um pouco.  A comparação linear (100 vs 100k) realmente é difícil, assusta (!), parece absurda, mas é a decisão do SO de como destacar usuários maduros de novatos, destacar usuários que "chamam *page-views*" de usuários que não chamam.

Parece absurda pois "o que se compra" com 100 é bem diferente do que se compra com 100k. Parece razoável pois quem é "super" gastou mais horas e soube atrair mais *page-views*... **A dúvida que fica é se existe um meio termo melhor, ou se o SO está perfeito como está.**

### Fontes de riqueza

Qual o perfil (estatístico!) das perguntas/respostas mais votadas do SO? Aquelas que recebem visitas, votos e comentários às centenas?

São, afinal, elas as principais "fontes de riqueza" do SO.

A melhor referência é o SO-en, muito mais maduro e com uma estatística muito mais confiável... A seguir uma lista de **causas (observadas) mais comuns para a popularidade**:

- Perguntas de sucesso focadas em aspectos das linguagens de programação:

  - **Manuais mal feitos**: é uma "percepção estatística", muito longe de qualquer trabalho analítico sério... O principal motivo de todos nós enchermos de votos algumas perguntas/respostas do SO, é a precariedade dos manuais. Linguagens populares como o PHP e frameworks populares como o jQuery, são ou já foram grandes fontes de "manuais incompetentes". Não é sempre, mas é comum aparecerem *posts* desse tipo com votações enormes, "descomunais".
    A explicação seria que, por serem problemas que deixam os programadores profundamente irritados, geram uma quantidade de votos muito maior que o "merecido".
  - **Deficiência da linguagem**: existem "partes mal feitas" de certas linguagem de programação. (p. ex. o PHP permite duplicidade de funções nativas e pipocam perguntas sobre qual melhor usar). Os usuários da linguagem ficam muitíssimo agradecidos por um posicionamento mais parcial e pelos votos que estabeleceram esse posicionamento. Por isso, e talvez por se somar a mesma irritação de manual mal feito, a votação descomunal.
- Perguntas de sucesso focadas em problemas (e não tanto nas linguagens ou *frameworks*):

  - **Problemas reais da moda**: de tempos em tempos o mercado cria demandas novas, que todos os programadores e analistas correm para atender. Com as novas demandas encaramos novos problemas... E ficamos muitíssimo agradecidos quando encontramos rápida e objetivamente a solução deles. Possuem seu mérito (!), mas o número de votos que recebem pode parecer descomunal. É a dinâmica do mundo real, os pioneiros recebem mais muito muito pontos. 
    Os votos desse tipo de problema "bombam" no inicio, criando um imenso pico na *origem* do  *gráfico VxT*.
  - **Problemas clássicos**: ... nunca sucatem ou "saem de moda"... São os problemas cuja solução realmente "possui mérito"... Os votos desse tipo de problema podem não saltar no inicio, mas geram um pinga-pinga quase contínuo de votos... Depois de 1 ano se destacam com dezenas ou centenas de votos.

NOTA: quais dessas "causas de popularidade" são mais ou menos merecedoras de mérito?  **Como caracterizar um *post* como "altamente popular"?**   Podemos propor que os **ganhos de pontos por *posts altamente populares* sejam atenuados?**

### Considerações sobre o conceito de mérito no SO

... O que é "mérito"? Faltou caracterizar... Ou será que o SO-en já caracterizou?

Publicar uma solução no SO não é o mesmo que publicar numa revista científica, mesmo se guardadas as devidas proporções.
O chamado "mérito científico", que poderíamos usar como referência para a noção de mérito no SO, se baseia no "ineditismo global", é quase como uma patente... Portanto, talvez não seja adequado. **O ineditismo exigido pelo SO é apenas local**, o *post* precisaria ser "inédito apenas dentro do próprio SO".
PS: como observamos, os *posts* do SO podem ser cópias descaradas de outras fontes, muitas inclusive sem citação da fonte.

Existe um outro "atrativo digno de mérito", nas perguntas e respostas bem votadas do SO: ser **sucinto e didático**.  Parece que isso além de observável é consenso (!).

Resumindo (parece que): **tem mérito no SO o *post* que consegue ser sucinto, didático, localmente inédito... e gerar muitos *page-views*.**

PS: cabe lembrar que "localmente inédito" no caso do SO-pt significa inclusive "sem compromisso com o SO-en", não perderíamos pontos se copiássemos e traduzíssemos descaradamente sem citar a fonte.

---

#### Consolidando posições através do  *modelo de referêcia*

Exemplos de como a discussão parece ficar mais simples e objetiva quando usamos um *modelo de referência*:  (entre aspas as colocações do @mgibsonbr)

- "Os pontos de reputação são baseados em mérito": apesar do [@mgibsonbr ter demonstrado que "é falso"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1826/4186), há que se considerar a conclusão oposta, se concordamos com a definição de mérito que ora deduzimos do *modelo*. Em tal contexto os pontos da pergunta são "mérito por comparação", e os pontos da resposta são "mérito por decisão democrática".
- "quem atribui o voto não está necessariamente qualificado para avaliar o mérito alheio". Pela definição de mérito do *modelo*, está sim qualificado... O que se pode questionar é se o usuário estaria "comprometido com o SO". O conceito de "*maturidade do usuário*" pode ajudar a discutir e colocar propostas nesse sentido.
- "Como julgar alguém que tem mais conhecimento que você?". Na Wikipedia fazem isso o tempo todo, sem precisar dos doutores das faculdades ou de prêmios Nobel. Se a resposta do SO foi útil para mim, para você e para o Fulano, foi porque todos nós julgamos a resposta útil (!), e, em média, o nosso conhecimento não é desprezível, não podemos ser desqualificados como "juízes da resposta". Não é um  "selo de qualidade" valioso, mas podemos reclamar *legitimidade* de nosso julgamento, sempre que tiver sido honesto, trata-se de um dos pilares da Democracia.
- "Quem contribui mais ganha mais reputação". Verdadeiro: o modelo parece concordar com o @mgibsonbr.
- "Quem tem maior poder de moderação tem mais influência". O modelo não diz nada sobre isso, pois não se preocupou em descrever as regras do SO, já bem descritas. As regras do SO impõe que apenas quem tem muita reputação seja moderador (!), o que não é tão democrático, mas é meritocrático. O @mgibsonbr questiona, todavia, o real poder de um moderador, e lembra que poder maior tiveram os *early adopters*.
- "O SO é ou não é uma Meritocracia?". Aqui vale a "primeira aproximação" (o SO se parece com muitas coisas, mas com qual se parece mais?). O *modelo* apenas define mérito e o significado dos votos, e deixa claro que a prática da gratificação pode ser qualificada como fonte de poder econômico. Pelas regras do SO, há uma correlação entre riqueza e direito ao exercício da moderação. Como lembrado pelo @utluiz, e como demonstrou-se pelo *modelo*,  os pontos de reputação podem ser interpretados como mérito... há  "empoderamento do mérito", portanto **é, em primeira aproximação, uma meritocracia**.
- ... mais exemplos? Parece realmente que o *modelo de referência* facilita o expressar de posições, conceitos, etc.? ...

Comment: "Na Wikipedia fazem isso o tempo todo, sem precisar dos doutores das faculdades ou de prêmios Nobel" A Wikipedia é uma enciclopédia - uma fonte **terciária** de conhecimento. Depois que um conhecimento (ex.: dissertações, teses) é publicado (fonte primária), e essa publicação é reconhecida por outras fontes como notória (fonte secundária), então ele se torna elegível para entrar na Wikipedia desde que acompanhada da citação de fontes. Verificar se uma descrição corresponde ou não à fonte citada é fácil. Verificar se ela é **correta**, isso já é bem mais difícil...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, precisamos lembrar do  "contexto SO", onde entram ferramentas como http://jsfiddle.net/ e http://hithub.com/, e, sobretudo, o código-fonte postado nas respostas... Essas "ferramentas" efetivamente ajudam cada um de nós a *"auditorar a verdade"*... Elas não existem na Wikipedia, nem possuem similares para outras áreas do conhecimento científico.

Comment: Com certeza, esse problema é reduzido nas ciências exatas em geral (mesmo se uma fonte "confiável" faz uma afirmação falsa, podemos refutá-la com relativa facilidade). Não discordo dos seus argumentos, meu comentário se referia especificamente à situação da Wikipedia.

Answer (score -3):

... o @mgibsonbr comentou o [sistema ELO do xadrez](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_ELO), o @Patrick deu a largada, fez uma primeira proposta... O @peterkrauss e o @mgibsonbr discutiram a ideia das gratificações mínimas....

Usando o [modelo de referência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1830/4186) podemos discutir os prós e contras mais objetivamente de cada proposta, bem como especificá-las com termos e conceitos mais precisos.

## PROPOSTAS

... EM CONSTRUÇÃO ... mas não AQUI!

**[Poste a sua proposta NESTA OUTRA PERGUNTA](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1837/4186).**

Comment: Sugestão: abra uma nova pergunta, no formato "pesquisa de opinião" (*poll question*), fazendo referência para esta e permitindo que cada um expresse uma ideia (ou proposta) como uma resposta separada. Assim podemos prosseguir a discussão sem "desvirtuar" o formato Q&A. Com o benefício adicional de permitir às pessoas votarem nas propostas individuais, e comentar nas mesmas. Nota: meu voto negativo não é porque sou contra discutir propostas - sou a favor - mas sim porque sou contra discutir propostas **aqui**, nessa resposta wiki.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Ok, muito mais sensato, obrigado!  [Está aberta a nova pergunta para este fim](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1837/4186).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, acatei a sugestão, achei simples e sensata... Mas estão "detonando", [pode dar uma ajuda por lá](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1837/4186)? Talvez, também, se alguem postar uma resposta, mesmo que rascunho...

Comment: Deixei uma resposta lá, só não sei se você vai gostar hehe. Não achei que estavam "detonando", simplesmente estão (assim como também estou) meio perplexos com a situação toda. Eu gostei da sua iniciativa, inclusive porque me levou a pensar (essas coisas de mérito, riqueza, etc, são muito relevantes na vida real), mas como os outros não vejo muito bem aonde é que isso iria levar, nem o que você pretende com essa discussão toda. Você fez a pergunta, respondeu a si próprio e está agora "chamando para a ação" com base principalmente no seu próprio modelo de referência. A pergunta é: "por que?" :P

Comment: Hum... acho que captei. Parece que quero cutucar o *status quo*...  Num primeiro momento queria entender melhor o que funciona, e o que não funciona... Mas não existem modelos nem estatísticas publicadas, então é preciso analisar a caixa preta. Pedi aos "colegas de comunidade" para me ajudarem a entender a caixa preta... Agora penso ter entendido melhor, já que as objeções não foram dirigidas ao modelo de referência.  O que não funciona? Sei que a "desigualdade" desanima e afugenta participantes. Não custa sugerir, e, discutindo as sugestões, entenderemos ainda melhor a caixa preta (!).