# Pesquisa de opinião, ajustes finos no uso da pontuação

Tags: debate, reputação

Essa pergunta teve origem em "[Estamos vivenciando uma experiência meritocrática?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/4186)" e na [sugestão do @mgibsonbr](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1836/4186)... Lá um dos itens para debate era

> 2- Discutir e sugerir pequenas melhoras, pequenos ajustes -- (...) para reduzir as enormes desigualdades de riqueza, (...), e usar outras fontes como a quantidade de votos. (...)

Mas foi muito ambicioso querer tudo no mesmo lugar.
Na discussão sobre "meritocracia" surgiram posicionamentos e consensos sobre as reais possibilidades de uma comunidade SO. Também surgiram propostas para pequenos ajustes, e aqui está sendo o local para postar e votar essas propostas.

**Abaixo cada um pode expressar uma proposta ou ideia**, como resposta separada. Assim podemos prosseguir a discussão sem "desvirtuar" o formato Q&A.

---

### LEMBRETES

Usando o [modelo de referência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1830/4186) podemos discutir os prós e contras mais objetivamente de cada "proposta de ajuste ou mudança no uso dos pontos de reputação", bem como especificá-las com termos e conceitos mais precisos. Sugere-se ainda abrir para Wiki cada resposta, para  forçar a consolidação e não a duplicação de propostas semelhantes.

[Na discussão inicial](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/4186) o @mgibsonbr comentou o [sistema ELO do xadrez](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_ELO), o @Patrick deu a largada, fez uma primeira proposta... O @peterkrauss e o @mgibsonbr discutiram a ideia das gratificações mínimas... Temos subsídios para começar!

Comment: Eu achei que a [resposta do utluiz](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1828/3117) tratou muito bem esse assunto, principalmente na parte que ele questiona: `Isso seria algum tipo de sistema socialista com redistribuição de renda?`. Ou seja, qual é a motivação de reduzir a desigualdade? Você não acha justo que quem recebeu mais votos tenha mais pontos? Pois eu acho. Você poderia explicar um pouco mais esse ponto em questão? Pois sinceramente não vejo como contribuir para sua pergunta mais que já contribuíram no outro tópico.

Comment: @Math, acho que suas colocações foram (e podem ser mais ainda) [discutidas na questão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/4186), a sua colocação pessoal poderia também ser postada por lá. Vale apenas reforçar para que demais leitores não confundam: 1) antes de responder *aqui*, [ler ali](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/4186); 2) se você não concorda em perder tempo com propostas, o ainda não entendeu a finalidade das propostas, basta não participar.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que eu acho que as resposta que estão lá já trataram bem do assunto, então eu acho que poderia ser interessante você adicionar na sua pergunta o por quê que o que está lá não está satisfatório. A resposta do utluiz tratou sobre isso, você discorda? Concorda parcialmente? Pois senão vira duplicação de texto. Sobre minha opinião, vão vou coloca-la lá em forma de texto, pois já pus ela em forma de voto.

Comment: Comentário baseado na minha opinião pessoal: Acho que tanto essa quanto a outra questão fogem da forma como programadores geralmente enxergam o mundo. Números, definições simples. Se uma thread do seu programa está trabalhando mais ela merece mais créditos. O que não quer dizer que ela é a melhor. Mas você não precisa de saber qual é a melhor, simplesmente quer valorizar o esforço de alguém. Para mim, o SO não tem por finalidade tanta discussão sobre a comunidade em si. **O principal deve ser o site principal e as perguntas de programação.** O resto é um agradecimento a quem contribui.

Comment: Se você tem alguma proposta específica (ou quer incorporar alguma sugestão que foi dada), por que não fazê-la diretamente? . . . . O que significa *"ajuste fino no uso da pontuação"*? E qual opinião exatamente você está procurando? . . . . . PS: quando alguém fala de si mesmo em 3ª pessoa me dá a impressão que estão tentando me vender a Torre Eiffel ou lançar a candidatura para deputado ;)

Comment: PS2: não li nem participei da discussão anterior, tenho que ler todo o material de referência pra poder entender esta? . . . . . E por que motivo esta pergunta não deve ser fechada como "principalmente baseada em opiniões"? `Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.`

Comment: Prezados, era para ser simples e direto, mas as objeções foram forçando dezenas de preâmbulos, como se fossemos botar o dedo numa casa de marimbondos... A proposta inicial foi simples, *perguntar de  "funções alternativas na matemática dos pontos"*... Como programadores, todos temos interesse em saber como ajustar o "algoritmo da comunidade" (!)  Enfim, espero que este seja o espaço para falar disso, pois **não encontrei em local algum tutorias explicando "como otimizar meritocracias"**. Com algumas respostas vai ficar mais claro... Ou vão pedir para fechar esse espaço de discussão de uma vez.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Acho que você iria gostar [dessa proposta no Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification?referrer=PrcPTht8fWb4DMkBFIDkbA2), se chegar ao beta seria o lugar perfeito para discussões desse tipo. Eu mesmo participei de [uma iteração anterior](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification), que infelizmente foi encerrada após o beta privado.

Answer (score 11):

### Sugestão: deixar tudo como está

A ideia é dar propostas e deixar que a comunidade vote nas mesmas - no meu entendimento, para que as bem aceitas eventualmente virem pedidos de "novo recurso". Entretanto, gostaria de expor meus argumentos em favor de "deixar tudo como está". Não fazer ajustes finos no sistema de pontuação.

Motivo: o principal problema que consigo identificar com o sistema atual:

- Uma pergunta passa despercebida (*tumbleweed*); se o usuário não tem reputação suficiente para oferecer uma recompensa, ele não tem meios **formais** de chamar à atenção à pergunta.

Não possui como melhor solução alterar o sistema de pontuação, pois:

1. O usuário pode usar de meios **informais** para chamar a atenção à pergunta (ex.: perguntar no chat), ou talvez editá-la colocando mais informações (*bump* na aba "ativo").
2. Alterações nos requisitos para gratificar seriam ineficazes, pelas razões já explicadas em [comentário na pergunta linkada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1825/estamos-vivenciando-uma-experi%C3%AAncia-meritocr%C3%A1tica/1836?noredirect=1#comment5362_1828).

Os demais pontos eu considero como "não problemas":

- Usuários com poucos pontos não têm poder de moderação (familiaridade com o site é requisito básico pra auxiliar na moderação);
- A escala linear torna a diferença entre 100 e 100k pontos "gritante" (irrelevante na prática, mais sobre isso adiante);
- Quem tem 100k de reputação pode passar a vida toda oferecendo recompensas - destacando os assuntos de seu maior interesse (cada usuário tem um limite de 3 recompensas simultâneas; você "tem a riqueza" mas não pode "esbanjá-la" como quer);
- Postagens populares recebem uma quantidade desproporcional de votos (só é problema se essa postagem é **ruim** - incentivando outras semelhantes - e já temos a ferramenta certa pra lidar com isso, o fechamento);

Creio que abordei todos os pontos citados no modelo de referência. Para fechar, um comentário sobre o que na minha opinião seria a preocupação central (estritamente do ponto de vista da gamificação, é claro):

> Se um usuário não vê perspectiva de progresso isso o desestimula a participar.

Na minha experiência como *gamer* de longa data, os pontos são um estímulo poderoso no início - perceber que suas ações estão dando resultados imediatos, ao contrário da vida real, em que se despende muito esforço e muitas vezes sem consequências visíveis. Essa característica que, tristemente, é muito usada por empresas pouco escrupulosas para nos viciar nos seus jogos. E que, felizmente, está agora sendo usada para propósitos mais nobres, na forma da gamificação.

Entretanto, esse estímulo se esvai com o tempo: chega uma hora que a gente não liga mais pros pontos! No SOen, por exemplo, eu sei que jamais alcançarei o Jon Skeet, mas eu poderia propor um desafio pessoal - por exemplo, chegar aos 20k, *trusted user* - e continuar perseguindo-o. Por que então eu parei de participar do SOen há mais ou menos um ano e meio? **Porque eu me cansei!** Achar perguntas boas era como procurar uma agulha no palheiro. A sensação de ajudar os outros continua boa, mas não o bastante pra eu continuar fazendo a mesma coisa dia após dia, de modo repetitivo. Não estava me entretendo. Não estava aprendendo. Então parei! No máximo uma vez por semana passava o olho nas perguntas com *bounty* à procura de alguma interessante, depois ia embora.

O mesmo ocorre aqui. Eu acesso todo dia, mas tirando aqueles dias em que estou mais "animado", fico apenas uns minutos por dia. Minha média recente de respostas está abaixo de 1 por dia. Do ponto de vista da gamificação, isso faz sentido? Não, pois eu estou menos de 200 pontos abaixo do 1º lugar, eu deveria estar estimulado a me esforçar bastante nesse momento. Mas não estou. Os pontos - e o ranking - não significam muita coisa pra mim... Meu maior estímulo é aprender (eu aprendo demais aqui, tanto perguntando quanto tentando responder), o segundo é acumular um "portfólio" interessante (não estou procurando emprego, mas nunca se sabe...), e o terceiro é ajudar mesmo (nunca pensei em seguir carreira acadêmica, mas descobri aqui que gosto de ensinar).

Desculpe se me desviei demais, mas o que quero dizer é que os pontos são um bom pretexto, mas não são eles que vão fazer um usuário desinteressado ficar no site, ou um interessado sair do site. De modo que apenas defendo ajustes finos em resposta a um problema perceptível no sistema atual. Não acompanho o [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (onde esse tipo de discussão ocorre há longa data) e não sei que já foi discutido lá, o que já foi descartado, o que poderíamos acrescentar, etc. Creio que uma boa familiaridade com esse site seria pré-requisito para opinar aqui (pra mim pelo menos, que "só abro a boca quando tenho certeza" rsrs), apesar da barreira da língua. Mas - [como bem apontado por Kyllopardiun nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1837/pesquisa-de-opini%C3%A3o-ajustes-finos-no-uso-da-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment5374_1837) - estou um pouquinho mais interessado em participar do site do que em discutir sobre o site.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta como um todo, mas para mim seu penúltimo paragrafo foi perfeito! Só para completar, ao meu ver o SO tem um costume de te "ensinar" algumas coisas através de medalhas e reputação, a partir de um certo ponto você já adquiriu o hábito e continua fazendo por gosto, e não por recompensa. Um belo exemplo é a medalha Fanático, eu já ganhei ela faz uns 2 meses, mas eu continuo entrando todo dia. Sei que não vou ganhar uma segunda medalha por isso, mas eu continuo acessando por achar legal.

Comment: ... A discussão é bastante pertinente, os posicionamentos pessoais idem (!). Só achei meio reduntante o título, já que *não estamos "votando mudanças"* (talvez somente o Joel tenha esse poder!), mas apenas discutindo um mundo alternativo... Enfatizando para o leitor desavisado: **aqui nesta página estamos a fazer meramente um exercício de teoria e imaginação**.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Melhorou? Mudei a redação um pouco, não foi minha intenção bater de frente com a proposta de discussão. E sim, não estamos votando mudanças - para isso teríamos de abrir uma pergunta "novo-recurso", e se bem votada torcer para ela ser acatada ([o que pode não ocorrer apesar do apoio da comunidade](http://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)). Eu entendo e concordo que a ideia aqui é uma "pré-proposta" - um lugar para discutir ideias antes delas virarem propostas.

Comment: Gostei dessa resposta também. Eu tenho acompanhado toda essa discussão meio a distância porque realmente não entendo muito do assunto, mas me parece que os votos são muito mais úteis em regular a relevância do conteúdo do que o "mérito" dos participantes (nós é que damos valor demais pra esses *my precious* pontos). Pode ser que controlar muito rigidamente o uso da pontuação com intenção de "balancear" a dificuldade do "jogo" afete de forma ruim o processo de sinalização de relevância do conteúdo (que, até onde eu entendo, funciona bem no SO em médio e longo prazo).

Answer (score 1):

## Taxação progressiva

O [modelo de referência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1830/4186), até o momento (é uma Wiki pode-se alterá-lo para melhor), demonstra que **existem questões que "pagam muito muito mais" do que as outras**. Se, por exemplo, numa questão comum tenho chance de ganhar 5 ou 10 pontos; com o mesmo esforço, o mesmo conhecimento, mas com a sorte de cair nas graças de uma questão dessas, posso ganhar 100, 200 ou 1000 pontos.

---

*PROBLEMA*: o imbróglio é com as questões que levam a "ganhos muito muito acima do comum", não com os usuários que tiveram a sorte de editar *posts* vitoriosos nelas. Não é coisa boa pois "cria do nada" um monte de pontos. Conceitualmente, depois dos 10 ou dos 100, não houve esforço para conquistá-los; estatisticamente,  no [mercado de pontos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1841/4186) surgirão desequilíbrios por conta disso.

*PROPOSTA*:  nada "do outro mundo", pelo contrário, no primeiro mundo a [*taxação progressiva*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_tax) é a coisa mais praticada. Tal taxação justamente ajuda a corrigir os "excessos da sorte" no jogo do captalismo. 

PS: o SO pode continuar com a sua vertente de *game*, mas não precisa ser  cassino.

*COMO*: não  é tão simples, pois requer em primeiro lugar "votar" ou saber avaliar com estatísticas (de *page-views* por exemplo) quais seriem as ditas "questões muito muito fora do comum". Em seguida saber avaliar o quanto vai ser "taxado", ou seja, reduzido do número de votos recebidos.

### ALGORITMO DO "COMO"

Uma forma é reduzir o ganho de reputação por voto conforme a publicação ganha votos excessivos. Os votos representam a quantidade de pessoas que apoia aquela publicação, mas após um determinado limite eles deveriam deixar de valer tanta reputação, afinal o usuário já foi recompensado. [Por melhor que seja uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/517503), eu não acho que ela valha 130k pontos sozinha.

Um método é usar a seguinte formula para calcular quantos pontos o próximo voto vai valer:

```
f(x) =  clamp(15 - log(x)/log(1.5774), 0, 10)
```

Com essa formula o máximo que uma única postagem pode dar de reputação é 2000 pontos. Bastante, mas não excessivo. Aqui o ganho de reputação para os 1000 primeiros votos:

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8,
 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6,
 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5,
 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Problema é que uma formula assim é MUITO mais difícil de ser explicada do que "você ganha +10 por voto". Além disso, o valor "1.557" é um tanto quanto arbitrário para dar um limite redondo de 2000 pontos/postagem.

Comment: Isso faz um certo sentido, mas será que "reputação passiva" tem um peso muito grande? Experimente [essa query no Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189323/my-money-for-jam), ela dá uma ideia do quanto um usuário ganha "sem fazer nada" (ex.: eu no SOen ganho 3,37 pontos por dia por postagens antigas; no SOpt é bem mais: 14,23). Um cap na reputação passiva (seja em votos ou em tempo) de fato ajudaria a só continuar premiando quem continua contribuindo conteúdo novo ao site.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, no [modelo de referência](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1830/4186) chamei esse "ganho sem fazer nada" de "pinga-pinga", e recebe-los é caracteristica de *usuário maduro*... Recebo "devagar e sempre" por exemplo  [dessa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948) e [dessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10498590/287948). O que discuto acima é outro tipo de *post*, aqueles de extremo sucesso como [este](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/287948) ou [este outro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/287948), que "pagam muito muito mais" que o normal.

Comment: Acho que eu vou parar por aqui, porque minha cabeça já está rodando... Se reputação passiva não é ruim, por que postagens com votações extremas são ruins? Estão atraindo *page-views*, não? Se fosse um caso dos pontos virem pelos motivos errados (ex.: se *code golf* for aceito aqui, e muito mais gente votar neles do que nas perguntas "úteis" de verdade), vá lá! Mas se um usuário demonstrou conhecimento a ponto de "impressionar" a comunidade (1º exemplo seu), ou se construiu material de referência útil a um público grande (2º exemplo), por que diabos o autor não merece seus pontos?!

Comment: Se entendi bem, isso já existe na forma do *reputation cap*: ninguém pode ganhar mais de 200 pontos por dia em upvotes (ou seja, 20 upvotes). Depois do vigésimo voto, os demais não rendem pontos. Aceitação de resposta e recompensas ficam fora dessa conta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nossa, que achado! O que é esse "reputation cap"? tem um link, mais didático e oficial, para os leitores?

Comment: Está explicado na [help]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @bfavaretto Bem lembrado! Acho que já li em algum lugar que a (uma das?) motivação por trás desse cap é justamente atenuar esses casos em que uma postagem fica "viral" de uma hora pra outra.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, sobre "por que postagens com votações extremas são ruins?", acho que já expus a minha visão pessoal várias vezes nessa discussão... É pessoal, mas é a seguinte: 10 é bom, 20 ainda é bom, 50 ainda seria bom... 1000 é demais!!  Desequilibra, destoa, destrói a "ecologia da comunidade", gera dominância extrema de poucos.

Comment: Uma discussão interessante em inglês sobre o rep cap: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Comment: Mais um belo achado do @bfavaretto. Interessante esse  trecho da resposta do Adam, "Far from preventing or limiting addiction, it feeds the addiction by forcing users to come back every day to get their hit.". Ele lembra que a forma como está hoje implmentado o rep cap não é para "reduzir riqueza", ou incentivar novos usuários, mas sim incentivar o usuário com perfil de "gammer" e já bem reputado. Eu não consideraria o *rep cap*, como está hoje, um exemplo de "taxação progressiva" tal qual proposto.

Answer (score -1):

## Limite (*cap*) na reputação de quem não vota

É preciso estimular os usuários a votar e aceitar respostas às suas perguntas (mas sem [antagonizar os usuários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/177950), é claro). Pode-se argumentar que ambos são fatores essenciais no sucesso do site, e se um usuário **nunca** pratica essas ações é provável que ele não esteja suficientemente familiarizado com ele (não importa quantas perguntas ele já fez).

Partindo então do pressuposto que "os pontos refletem a familiaridade do usuário com o site" e "usuários com mais pontos têm maior poder de moderação" temos que faz sentido - ao menos do ponto de vista lógico - impedir o progresso de um usuário se ele não demonstrou ter conhecimento suficiente da mecânica do site para receber privilégios de moderação.

Isso pode ser implementado impondo um limite superior à reputação **total** do usuário proporcionalmente ao seu número de votos e/ou "accept-rate" (se isso ainda existe, mesmo que oculto). Os pontos "perdidos" por atingir-se o cap podem ou não ser ressarcidos quando o usuário cumprir sua "cota" de votos. Se o usuário optar por continuar não votando, ainda é um direito dele.

Comment: Não sei se entendi a ideia, parece boa. Eu até ia editar para corrigir um detalhe, mas não sei se entendi: o que seria *CAP*? Não seria melhor explicar para o "leitor qualquer"?   Talvez acrescentando também algum link oficial do SO que usa e explica o termo *"reputation cap"*...

Comment: Um mecanismo assim não poderia causar um surto de votação ilegítima/inútil? Tipo, um usuário, preocupado em não ter o seu *incoming* de votos limitado poderia sair distribuindo votos positivos arbitrariamente (até porque, votar positivamente não tem custo algum).

Comment: @LuizVieira Como eu comentei [em uma outra pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1803/215), eu concordo - qualquer incentivo a votar pode sair pela culatra, se for "atraente" demais. É bem mais difícil garantir a honestidade de votos do que edições e fechamentos, por exemplo. Teria que ser uma coisa sutil e mínima. De todo modo, coloquei essa sugestão mais como *brainstorming*, não estou particularmente interessado em mudanças nos mecanismos de pontuação.

Comment: Acho que poderia haver um aumento no *cap* de 200 para quem vota e deixar como está para quem não voto. Mas também acho que essa proposta ficaria no campo do *brainstorming* mesmo. Não é o tipo de coisa que a SE se preocupa em melhorar.

Answer (score -3):

## Repensando a gratificação

### preâmbulos

Como colocado pelo @mgibsonbr, os nossos *pontos de reputação* podem ser imaginados como pontos em um *game*.  Buscar mais pontos pelo "prazer de jogar", por subir no ranking,  para ficar bonito no Careers... São estímulos à acumulação de pontos,  ao melhor estilo *game*. 
PS: também existe o "prazer de ensinar", a "necessidade de se exercitar", etc. mas não são o carro-chefe do SO.

Não é nenhuma crise, mas pessoas que sabemos que poderiam estar no SO, que tem perfil, nem entram, não se interessam pelo "game". Outros acham que o "game" ficou muito concorrido, coisa de viciado...  E é fato medido: muitos usuários aparecem, criam login, mas não ficam.

Vem ganhando lentamente mais adeptos um outro tipo de estímulo no SO, e há quem diga que  estar meio "de lado", meio sub-utilizado. Ele contrasta um pouco com essa visão de *game*, é muito mais uma motivação concreta do mundo real, muitos usuários viram no SO uma oportunidade de "consultoria grátis", e não há nada de mal nisso (!).

### Pontos de reputação financiando consultorias

Quando optamos por fazer uso do **[sistema de gratificação do SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)**, transformamos  "consultoria média grátis" em uma "consultoria boa paga". Pagamos, pois  abrimos mão dos nossos "suados" pontos de reputação...

Quantas consultorias dessas podemos financiar?  Quando "sentimos no bolso" e quando elas ainda se parecem grátis?  A conta é simples: para quem tem 100k é grátis,  para quem tem 1k, dá pra sentir.

Existe um "limiar de riqueza", subjetivo, mas muito claro, que eu chutaria em 500 pontos, abaixo do qual é arriscado gastar. A justificativa é bem conhecida:

> Reputação é uma medida (muito) aproximada de quanto a comunidade SO confia em você. Reputação nunca é dada, ela é conquistada, convencendo outros usuários SO que você sabe o que você está falando.
>   [@JeffAtwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Abaixo do tal limiar, você não convence, se sente "excluído da comunidade e do *game*".

### Usando os pontos de reputação como se fossem *bitcoins*!

Quem não está preocupado em subir no ranking, quem quer apenas "treinar um pouco", "ensinar um pouco"... e fazer as suas consultorias... Esse tipo de usuário pode ter uma visão diferente dos pontos de reputação (acima do limiar). **Para esse usuário os pontos são quase como [Bitcoins](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin)**.

*PROPOSTA*: estimular esses usuários!

*COMO*: dando mais chances, e desde mais cedo (antes de perder para sempre o usuário), para ele "participar no mercado das gratificações".

### ALGORITMO DO "COMO"

É algo que requer ajustes/calibrações, sobretudo depois de boas análises estatísticas, mas não é muito diferente de uma  *análise de mercado*.  Como no caso do [câmbio de moedas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2mbio_de_moeda), pode até ser algo dinâmico, que [flutue](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2mbio_flutuante) conforme a demanda na comunidade como um todo.

ESBOÇO: para "atrair mais cedo" é simples, basta tornar a participação mais barata. Hoje o SO-pt exige um mínimo de 50 pontos (e as opções são múltiplos de 50). Ao usuário pobre poderia ser dada a opção de mínimo de 20, e múltiplos de 10. Para o usuário milionário, mínimo de 500 e multiplos de 100 ou de 500...

Comment: Dois comentários: 1) no meu entender, os pontos não têm utilidade no Carrers; o que vale é um *showcase* das suas melhores respostas (você pode escolher quais delas - e de quais sites - aparecem no seu perfil público). 2) Sobre essa "consultoria grátis", recompensas não justificam perguntas "ruins". Eu estou nesse exato momento atolado em dúvidas por causa de um projeto grande que minha empresa está tentando pegar, mas não me atrevo a buscar ajuda aqui na forma de perguntas - a grande maioria delas seria negativada e fechada num piscar de olhos (por ser subjetiva, ampla, ou baseada em opinião)

Comment: P.S. Como entusiasta das cripto-moedas, me dói na alma ver uma comparação dos Bitcoins com os pontos de reputação do SO hehe! :P

Answer (score -3):

Quando discutido aqui no Meta [Por que as pessoas estão votando tão pouco?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1813/4186)
a opinião foi unânime: o esforço de votar é pequeno, mas tem o seu mérito!

## Sugestão de premiar o voto

Voto precisa de estímulo: se acada 50 ou 100 votos eu ganhar um ponto? é pouco, mas passa a ser um estímulo.

Não podem haver recompensas relevantes pois incentivariam "voto sem pensar", além de desincentivar o "suor" de quem postou algo.

Comment: Existe a medalha [Eleitorado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) que tem como propósito justamente estimular os votos. Não estou dizendo que sua ideia é ruim, só estou dizendo que o SE já pensou em algo do tipo, entretanto optaram por fazê-lo dando uma medalha de ouro.