# Por que não posso perguntar qualquer coisa sobre programação no StackOverflow Pt?

Tags: debate

Sou um usuário novo e percebo que há restrições e solicitação de modificação as perguntas que faço. Em específico a minha pergunta foi classificada como **["Gorilla vs. Shark"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/3117)**

**Qual o problema de perguntar o que quero sobre programação da forma que eu quero?**

**Por que todas perguntas não podem coexistir?**

Comment: Porque no SOpt só tem experts e filósofos que acham que todo mundo fez faculdade e sabe exatamente quais palavras ou expressões ou frases usar. Deixando de lado a ironia, se não existisse padrões ia virar uma bagunça.

Comment: Aparentemente não há qualquer problema. E a prova disto é que o Yahoo! Respostas aceita perguntas de programação da forma como qualquer um quer. As perguntas de todos os tipos coexistem lá. É um excelente lugar para se desenvolver como um bom profissional, todo mundo sabe disto. É uma fórmula vencedora. Ou será que estou errado?

Comment: Eu lembro quando o Programmers deu uma guinada de aceitar qualquer coisa para adotar a fórmula atual de toda a rede da SE. Muitas pessoas ficaram revoltadas. Me lembro que várias vezes os principais nomes da SE falarem que eles podiam tentar usar fundar um site com uma fórmula diferente e ver se teria o mesmo sucesso. Se alguém acredita tanto que a fórmula da SE está errada, pode procurar um site que tenha uma fórmula melhor ou pode até mesmo fazer um site com uma fórmula melhor.

Comment: Eu não compreendo duas coisas. Porque a SOpt é tão importante se ele está desagradando (deve existir opções melhores) e porque as pessoas acham mais fácil ficar debatendo isto do que fazer um esforço em melhorar sua pergunta e obter sucesso no que deseja.

Comment: bigown, é bem fácil colocar a pergunta em inglês no google e obter a resposta bem rápido, normalmente já aparece no W3 ou no SOen(nem que seja num cache por aí do SOen). Mas acho importante que essa informação fique na internet para os que não sabem inglês. Por isso quis saber de onde surgiu essas restrições. Se re-escrevo a minha pergunta de forma mais adequada, outra pessoa que procura essa resposta usando as mesmas palavras que usei na forma inicial pode não achar a pergunta.

Comment: +1 por trazer suas dúvidas ao Meta. Se tiver interesse em saber em detalhes porque o site é como é, confira os arquivos das [(meta) Perguntas frequentes](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent). E acho que pra embasar melhor sua interpretação das regras locais (sopt) e globais (stack exchange) vale uma leitura nas partes principais da [help].

Comment: PS: o nome do artigo é um trambolho também, programador vem perguntar sobre Ruby e caboclo vem falar pra ele de Gorilas e Tubarões! Foi mal ae, da próxima vou tentar um artigo mais leve :) {edit} Tipo [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)

Comment: hehehe, Pelo menos agora "Gorilas vs. Tubarões" tem uma resposta. Melhor uma resposta ruim do que nenhuma resposta.

Comment: @HamiltonCarmisinJunior A intenção ali não era ter resposta, é a tradução de um artigo do blog em inglês (mas tudo bem você ter respondido, acabou gerando esta discussão aqui que foi bem positiva para a comunidade).

Comment: @bfavaretto o botão de "responder a essa pergunta" estava ali habilitado pra mim mesmo eu sendo um usuário novo. Talvez suspender perguntas que na verdade são apenas artigos com um comentário "Este é apenas um artigo." seja uma solução.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para manter o site **focado**.

Eu sou a favor de existirem espaços para se perguntar qualquer coisa, inclusive é a principal razão pela qual eu gostaria que a *engine* do StackExchange fosse open source (e, na falta disso, fico feliz por existirem clones nessa modalidade) - pois embora existam zilhões de sites na rede ([eu também contei!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark/1944#comment5955_1944)) e outros tantos sendo propostos na [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), seria irreal esperar que uma única empresa dispusesse de graça dos recursos computacionais para absorver **todas** as perguntas sobre **tudo**...

Na Area 51 muitas propostas são fechadas pois se avalia que as mesmas não terão sucesso. Ora, "sucesso" é subjetivo, e minha concepção de sucesso pode ser diferente da sua. A StackExchange tem uma concepção bem delineada, que envolve entre outras coisas ter "muito sinal e pouco ruído". Em outras palavras, conteúdo útil e relevante pra muita gente, sem muito conteúdo inútil misturado.

E eles têm boas razões pra isso: nem sempre os "especialistas" - aqueles que detêm certo conhecimento e podem portanto contribuí-lo a outros - estão dispostos a fazê-lo de graça a estranhos na internet. Eu mesmo já respondi uma ou outra pergunta em um fórum qualquer, mas nunca me dediquei tanto tempo a um site quanto me dedico à StackExchange. Por que? Bom, certamente é porque estou ganhando alguma coisa em troca...

No meu caso particular, há o **reconhecimento** pelo meu esforço e minhas contribuições (acreditem, minha vida profissional está muito aquém do que se poderia esperar dada minha aparente reputação aqui), há o **aprendizado** que ganho perguntando e tentando responder - bem como lendo perguntas e respostas alheias - e há a facilidade de encontrar conteúdo bom ainda que eu não esteja especificamente procurando por ele (i.e. o sistema de votações ajuda a classificar o conteúdo do site, destacando aquilo que é mais interessante). Dentre outras coisas, é claro, mas isso são coisas que me vêm à cabeça agora, e que são relevantes para a discussão em pauta.

O que aconteceria se fôssemos mais liberais, não só em relação à qualidade das perguntas, mas também ao nível de subjetividade, ou mesmo ao escopo? O ruído cresceria bastante em relação ao sinal. Ficaria mais difícil encontrar conteúdo bom, de modo que eu provavelmente visitaria menos o site. A dificuldade de encontrar perguntas boas me fariam então deixar de respondê-las, de modo que meu conhecimento não iria beneficiar mais ninguém. Ok, sai um "especialista" e entra muitos "novatos", esses com seu próprio conhecimento e sua própria disposição em ajudar - nos seus próprios termos. A comunidade ganhou ou perdeu? Nenhum dos dois: a comunidade **mudou de composição**.

E é justamente *isso* que impede que esse foco seja mudado: a StackExchange **não quer** que a composição da comunidade mude dessa forma. Ela não quer se tornar mais um fórum de discussão, mais um local em que novatos ajudam novatos, e a informação tenha curta validade. A proposta desse site é outra, e as regras existem para realizar essa proposta.

Reiterando, não sou contra haver um espaço para perguntas que não se encaixam bem no formato do SOpt: eu próprio tenho **muitas** perguntas subjetivas que gostaria de fazer, mas não sei onde... Mas eu sou sim contra abrir demais o escopo *desse* site, para não acontecer dele virar um local muito disperso, onde é difícil encontrar as coisas que um usuário com meu perfil procura. Sou a favor de existirem múltiplos espaços, cada um voltado a um público-alvo específico - seja na própria rede StackExchange ou fora dela. Pois da mesma forma que uma biblioteca possui diferentes seções com livros de um determinado assunto - e não tudo misturado numa pilha só - também é bom existirem sites diferentes com características diferentes, e não tentar tratar o SOpt como "o último site que um desenvolvedor precisará na vida".

Comment: IMHO a melhor resposta (entre as anteriores boas também) até agora.

Comment: Fantástica essa resposta, no começo fiquei com um pouco de preguiça de ler (por ser grande) mas depois valeu cada palavra. Não sabia por exemplo que o site gerava benefícios profissionais aos mais assíduos. Seria bom se houvesse um SOpt iniciantes ou algo assim, essa área 51 é só inglês, muito colorida também. Só esperava que tivesse mais conteúdo em português sobre programação em algum lugar.

Comment: @HamiltonCarmisinJunior A Area 51 é tipo uma "incubadora" de novos sites, não necessariamente em inglês ([o próprio SOpt nasceu de lá, inclusive](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese)), mas de fato para se propor um site novo a discussão tem de ser em inglês mesmo... E quanto aos "benefícios profissionais", já viu o [Carreers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)? A ideia é os usuários da SE poderem postar suas contribuições como uma espécie de "portfólio" [de graça], e os empregadores em potencial poderem consultar os perfis dos usuários [pagando à SE].

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu só estou aqui porque desisti (tentando compreender de os companheiros darem downvote. Uso o SOpt quanto o em Inglês, e os moderadores de lá não são como os BRs e eu queria entender o porquê disso. Na home da SOpt você vê a lateral com os títulos já com downvotes. Eu em 6 anos de usuário ainda me considero aprendiz aqui. Parece que o site foi feito para um nível especifíco de usuários, e quem faz "perguntas burras" (sim, eu li o glossário como fazer uma pergunta) tem a avaliação negativa é quase imediata. Não é fazendo críticas, mas desincentiva quem está iniciando...

Answer (score 13):

O modelo do SO foi idealizado para gerar primariamente conteúdo de qualidade e relevante. E o sucesso do mesmo é, na verdade, uma consequência disso.

Alguns argumentam, por exemplo, que questões interessantes, independente de que tipo sejam, aumentariam a quantidade de visualizações do site e, consequentemente, a relevância e a renda da empresa por trás do site.

Porém, até onde eu li e ouvi do Joel e do Jeff (os fundadores), isso não será colocado em primazia, nunca. Isso implica em que, o fato de um certo tipo de conteúdo ser interessante ou gerar mais visualizações não é garantia de que ele é de interesse para o site.

Por exemplo, há algum tempo assisti a uma [apresentação do próprio Jeff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEc6Eyogb9Y) sobre o sistema do SO. Em um determinado momento, ele fala sobre a questão de aceitarem perguntas sobre o mercado de trabalho e diz que esse tipo de questão geralmente atrai bastante visitas e muito interesse naquele momento, porém a informação é rapidamente fica defasada, em geral é localizada e o conteúdo torna-se logo inútil, uma "sujeira" para quem entra no site.

Esse é o motivo para o site ter fama de ser mais "fechado" ou "linha dura".

Então, creio que, embora seja muito desejável que o site seja aberto a qualquer tipo de pergunta, os idealizadores iriam argumentar que isso atrairia conteúdo de baixa qualidade e a razão de ser do SO deixaria de existir. O SO seria então mais um fórum como tantos outros.

Veja, não estou dizendo que a equipe do SO não vai ou não quer melhorar o site, nem que eles são tão idealistas que nunca mudariam a forma como o SO funciona.

---

<sup>Nota: [adaptado de uma outra resposta minha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1828/227).</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ótima resposta. Eu meço o sucesso de um site justamente pelo número de acessos, usuários ativos, e capacidade de gerar renda com propagandas. É interessante pensar que os fundadores do SO não pensem assim. Também não acho que conteúdo inútil ou defasado incomode alguém; mas claro que essa decisão cabe aos fundadores e não a mim. De qualquer forma é fato que o próprio SO-en deixou muito conteúdo legado de perguntas de todo tipo, quando não havia nenhuma censura, e isso vai ficar na internet nem que seja só no cache dos servidores aí. Esse conteúdo só existe em inglês.

Comment: @HamiltonCarmisinJunior, falta um dado na sua medida de sucesso: a quantidade de especialistas/entusiastas que ***respondem*** é proporcional à qualidade das perguntas. O conteúdo antigo e off-topic hoje-em-dia lá no SOen costuma receber bloqueio-histórico e ser fechado ou mesmo deletado.

Comment: @brasofilo entendo perfeitamente a política de seguir o SOen. Agora, o que cada um entende como sucesso é bem subjetivo. Entendo que o facebook tenha sucesso mesmo que a maioria do conteúdo seja bobeira.

Comment: Não é a política do SOen, é a da rede [se]. E [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1/201) :)

Answer (score 13):

Entendo sua frustação de ter tido um embate com a comunidade logo na sua primeira pergunta. Mas saiba que você não foi o primeiro nem será o último. Não sei se te ajuda a entender, mas pense da seguinte forma: somos uma comunidade, todos nós usuários juntos somos praticamente um ser vivo, que cresce e se modifica ao longo do tempo.

Nossa comunidade nasceu em dezembro do ano passado, de lá para cá ela já mudou consideravelmente. Novos membros chegaram, alguns dos antigos aos poucos de afastaram, evoluímos, discutimos o que era bom e o que era ruim, e aos poucos fomos criando nossos hábitos e acordos do que é ou não interessante para nós mesmos. E ainda continuamos fazendo isso, e assim continuaremos para o resto dos tempos.

[Como eu já havia citado em outro tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1305/3117), eu diria que podemos nos comparar de forma análoga a um país, que também possui cultura e costumes. E quando uma pessoa que não está acostumada com essa cultura, ela sofre um certo impacto, até se acostumar ou abandonar de vez.

O ponto que eu quero chegar é o seguinte:

Não podemos aceitar qualquer coisa pois sabemos, graças à experiência que temos juntos, que algumas coisas não são boas para a comunidade, seja a curto, médio ou longo prazo.

Logo, independente do motivo pelo qual uma pergunta é fechada, negativada, ou comentada pedindo por aprimoramentos, saiba que estamos fazendo isso para o bem da comunidade (ou achamos que estamos). Queremos sim atrair e manter novos usuários na comunidade, entretanto não faremos isso a qualquer custo, queremos usuários que se adaptem à cultura da comunidade. Ao fazer isso, invariavelmente e indiretamente estamos expulsando pessoas, que não se sentem a vontade ou se sentem ofendidas por seja lá qual for o motivo.

Sabendo que é impossível agradar a todos, concluo que não há nenhum mal em fazer o que fazemos, que é moderar e orientar os usuários, principalmente os novos, sem nunca deixar de lado o [**carinho**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1333/3117) (que por sinal foi algo que concordamos que é algo positivo para a comunidade). E sempre deixando as portas abertas para novas discussões no Meta, que podem resultar em mais modificações na nossa forma de pensar.

Essa foi minha resposta para:

> Qual o problema de perguntar o que quero sobre programação da forma que eu quero?
>
> Por que todas perguntas não podem coexistir?

Se quiser saber a respeito da sua pergunta em específico, crie um tópico especialmente para ela.

Comment: Legal a sua resposta Math. Obrigado pela empatia, não estou frustrado não. Até agora (2 dias) estou achando bem legal. O chato seria ninguém falar nada. Até ganhei umas medalhas aí... Isso é divertido. Antes de me cadastrar pensava que era uma comunidade mais aberta a qualquer pergunta desde que fosse de programação, mas agora já entendi melhor a cultura, espero que essa pergunta sirva aos novos.

Comment: @Math obrigado pelo texto. Postei quase acima um comentário do utluiz de como fazer perguntas por aqui. Como desenvolvedor, estou começando a entender depois de 6 anos que vocês querem manter um nivel de qualidade das perguntas. Eu irei tentar ser mais sucinto e objetivo quando tentar contribuir

Answer (score 8):

Um adendo á resposta do utluiz.

O site tem um [**escopo fechado**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic). Dê uma olhada rápida na seção de ajuda, em especial [o que pode ser perguntado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), e [o que deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

O motivo do sucesso do SO original é essa forma de escopo fechado. Se você tem uma dúvida de programação específica, o Stack é o local no qual nove entre cada nove desenvolvedores pensam. Comparação entre linguagens e tecnologias é geralmente tangente a esse foco, o que torna perguntas desses temas complicadas de se lidar. Mas você pode melhorar sua pergunta e tê-la reaberta (veja os links acima).