# Pergunta do tipo: "Eis o que eu sei. Estou certo? Você tem algo a adicionar?"

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica, conteúdo

Esta pergunta surgiu na fila de revisão recentemente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141455/

Vejo que o OP está bem intencionado e que o assunto é interessante, então não quis votar para fechar... Por outro lado, acho muito difícil conseguir responder esse tipo de pergunta de maneira tradicional (i.e., chegar à uma resposta correta).

Poderíamos tentar responder criando wiki posts para cada uma das tecnologias abordadas, porém não sei se esse tipo de prática não seria uma deturpação dos mecanismos do site. Além do que, esse tipo de material provavelmente se encaixa melhor na descrição das tags.

Gostaria de saber o que devemos fazer com essa pergunta em específico? E mais do que isso, como devemos aconselhar usuários que façam perguntas desse tipo daqui para frente?

Comment: Capaz que dê pra responder de maneira mais ampla sobre SaaS e Cloud, sem se deter nos detalhes das plataformas citadas mas provavelmente falando de tipos/estilos de plataforma.

Comment: Creio que esse tipo de pergunta seja válido pois muita vezes achamos que algo é X mas na verdade não é. É melhor errar e ser corrigido do que  achar que você tem o conhecimento absoluto e espalhar mais desinformação.

Comment: Ao menos no caso do meu voto, o "Eis o que eu sei. Estou certo? Você tem algo a adicionar?” é irrelevante, pois o problema dessa pergunta é outro. Entendo que questões com muitos assuntos diferentes geralmente são amplas, e é o caso dessa no meu ver. E é essa a razão do meu voto de fechamento.

Comment: Precisamos tomar uma decisão até para aconselhar o OP (se a pergunta terminar fechada sem nenhum aconselhamento será horrível).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta original acabou sendo fechada nesse meio tempo por ser ampla demais. Lendo o [comentário do Bacco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5174/pergunta-do-tipo-eis-o-que-eu-sei-estou-certo-voc%c3%aa-tem-algo-a-adicionar#comment18786_5174) e a [resposta do rray](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5188/100) acredito que o consenso é que esse tipo de pergunta é um novelo de lã muito difícil de desembaraçar sem desrespeitar o formato do site.

Quanto aos usuários confundirem alhos com (...) bugalhos e criarem perguntas pouco objetivas, isso não é novo ([postei algo assim em 2014](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1766/100)), porém ainda me aborrece um pouco ver esse tipo de questão sendo fechada sem algum tipo de aconselhamento.

Concordo com o [comentário do Laerte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5174/pergunta-do-tipo-eis-o-que-eu-sei-estou-certo-voc%c3%aa-tem-algo-a-adicionar#comment18781_5174). Devemos ao menos apontar o usuário na direção correta, até para que esse tipo de pergunta não acabe se multiplicando. Já vi usuários frustrados postando variações da pergunta fechada antes.

Na ausência de um mecanismo como o [*Documentation*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) do SOen, minha sugestão para perguntas futuras é que ao menos deixemos um comentário apontando tags das respectivas tecnologias antes de fechar a pergunta.

### Exemplo:

Olá OP, infelizmente sua pergunta é ampla demais para ser respondida adequadamente no formato do SOpt. Há uma certa mistura dos conceitos de [cloud](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud), [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) e [ide](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) online na sua pergunta. Esses tópicos e a maneira como eles se relacionam merecem estudos separados. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre as tecnologias discutidas nas tags [heroku](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku) e [docker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker). Fique a vontade para fazer perguntas mais específicas sobre cada um dos assuntos.

---

Acredito que um comentário como esse poderia ajudar o OP e pessoas com dúvidas semelhantes. Também vamos chamar mais atenção para a descrição das *tags*. O corpo das *tags* é um excelente lugar para descrever e introduzir conceitos e tecnologias, bem como um bom lugar para linkar documentação e artigos relevantes para pessoas curiosas sobre determinado assunto como o OP.

Answer (score 2):

O problema desse tipo de pergunta é comparar assuntos/conceitos/tecnologias que são muito diferentes entre si. A primeira tentativa é encontrar alguma duplicata ou outras perguntas que expliquem o conceito, caso nenhuma das opções funcione o jeito é questionar o OP se tem dúvida algum ponto especifico, editar a pergunta e **corta o conceito alienígena** e comparar os similares, ou ainda sugerir ao OP que a atual pergunta seja quebrada em outras.

Comment: Esses tipos de perguntas podem estar dentro do escopo do sopt?