# Devemos parar esse [desenvolvimento]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica

Esbarrei com a tag [desenvolvimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desenvolvimento). Dei uma olhada nela, e no momento só tem 8 perguntas:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141455/132 (4 votos para fechar, +1 ponto, sendo discutida [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5174/132))
2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140754/132 (4 votos para fechar, -3 pontos)
3. [Ferramenta para trabalhar em grupo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127783/132) (-1 ponto)
4. [Padrão de projetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127661/132) (fechada, -1 ponto)
5. [Qual é a finalidade do virtualenv e por que não instalar globalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126852/132) (+3 pontos)
6. [Qual tipo de projeto usar para criar um jogo multiplayer no Construct 2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112170/132) (+3 pontos)
7. [Certificação de Processo de Qualidade: como obter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99911/132) (+3 pontos)
8. [Como é desenvolvido um Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98212/132) (+8 pontos)

Possivelmente podem haver mais algumas perguntas deletadas ou das quais a tag já foi excluída.

Vamos dar uma olhada nesta tag:

- Não tem wiki.
- É uma tag bem ampla e genérica e poderia se aplicar a pelo menos umas 90% das perguntas do site, mas no momento se aplica apenas a 8 perguntas bem diferentes entre si.
- Das 8 perguntas na qual ela está aplicada, 4 delas tem pontuação negativa ou votos para fechamento, sendo 1 delas fechada.
- Não fornece nenhuma informação relevante para categorizar a questão na qual é aplicada.

Eu poderia simplesmente remover a tag de todas essas questões e deixar que o sistema a delete automaticamente depois. Entretanto, acho bem provável que ela seja recriada posteriormente. Portanto, a minha sugestão é:

**Lista negra, *burninate*!**

Comment: Acho que já devia estar parado. É uma tag super abrangente e não interessa nada.

Comment: Por mim já poderia "passar a faca" nelas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removi a tag de todas as perguntas em que ela aparecia, mas no final ouvi ela dizer "eu voltarei!" ...

Comment: ahahahahhahahahahah

Comment: http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/88/8899/7HJP300Z/posters/the-terminator-i-ll-be-back.jpg

Comment: http://static.businessinsider.com/image/5527b6f6eab8ea4277fe871c/image.gif

Comment: Não tem como "banir" a criação de uma tag para evitar essa volta?

Answer (score 12):

A não ser que queira deixar ela como *honeypot* :P, ela é desnecessária. Tudo bem fundamento na pergunta.

Relacionada: [Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/101)